# Airfare Ticket Reduction Optimization Problem

Tags: calculus, optimization

I am a little confused as to this basic calculus question. I'll paste it here, it's from my school textbook.

> The airfare between Vienna and Dubai is approximately €500. An airline has a passenger capacity of 300, but at certain times of the year they only fly with an average of 180 passengers. After doing some market research, the airline finds out that for each reduction of €10 in ticket price below €500 they can attract two more passengers on each flight. Determine the best ticket price, and the corresponding number of passengers per flight, that would maximize the airline's revenues on this route.

I started with setting up some equations.

$$\textrm{price per ticket $p(x)$ (€)}=500-10x,\quad \textrm{where $x$ is the number of reductions from €500}$$
\begin{align*}\textrm{total revenue $r(x)$ (€)}&=(180+2x)\cdot p\\
&= (180+2x)(500-10x)\\
&=-20x^2-800x+90\ 000
\end{align*}

Then I established the constraints:

$$0\leq x\leq 50,\quad\textrm{there cannot be less than 0 reductions and price cannot be negative}$$

Then differentiating and setting to equal to find a maximum.

\begin{align*}r'(x)&=-40x-800\\
0&=-40x-800\\
40x&=-800\\
x&=-20
\end{align*}

However, $-20$ is not in the domain of $r$ so it must be discarded. Hence the maximum value for $r$ is one of the extremes within its domain. In this case, one can graphically confirm that the maximum revenue is obtained when there are no reductions and the tickets are sold at their normal 500 euro.

Yet the textbook claims that there is peak revenue when the tickets are sold at 300 euros. I feel like you can logically check that this is wrong. If the tickets are at 300 euros, there have been 20 reductions from 500 euros, hence 40 passenger extra. So the revenue would be $220\cdot 300=66\ 000$ which is clearly less than if one were to sell it at the normal price of 500 euros to 180 passengers (90 000).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What you are suggesting is that the optimal price is €700 with 140 passengers and a revenue of €96 000

Comment: No, because the question implies that the ticket price can be reduced but cannot be increased. The optimal price is then simply 500 euros with 180 passengers. But the book thinks otherwise. I will note: the book is known for errors, and usually I can check it, but here it's hard to find a quick way to check, especially as they give a very clear answer of 300 euros at 220 pax for some reason...